# HTML list items order

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to automatically limit the height of an HTML list based on the parent's height. Is it possible to not let the list visibly overflow, but place the overflowing elements next to each other and continue the iteration from there? The list is dynamic, so list item count could be 1 or 100.

I know that every third element reaches the max height of the element, so I could use a nth-child() selector. I prefer to do it in a more elegant way tho.

For example:

```
li 1    li 4    li 7
li 2    li 5
li 3    li 6
```

Comment: You could use `column-count`

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how many list elements there will be, so I don't know the amount of columns.

Comment: You don’t need to know number of columns, you set that to auto and size the list items to the height required so that there are always 3 per column. Unfortunately I am on a mobile device and can't make a demo.

Comment: @Paulie_D How would this provide the layout intended? What display should be set on the list items? The standard block? Or inline-block? Or floats?

Answer (score 0):

If your list items are filled dynamically then u should use loops (php), you can also play around with css nth-child() selector.

Use this if u know exactly how many list items u have.

```
   ul {
    columns: 3;
    -webkit-columns: 3;
    -moz-columns: 3;
   }
```

Comment: Yes, but what CSS properties could I use for the nth-child selector?

Comment: @Jesse nth-selector can give you the layout you described in your example, but won't solve your actual problem. Being that the elements should stack to the max height of it's parent.

Comment: For the height issue just use inherit. Do you work with php?

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that the max height is defined, so I basically know every third li element should break. @Krone I want to solve this CSS only

Comment: @Krone Now you've just taken Paulie_D's suggestion and implemented it wrong.

Comment: Yes it works for the demo amount of items. But if you actualy read the question, and the comments(which I'm sure you did as you got your own answer from there) you would have read the following: "The problem is that I don't know how many list elements there will be, so I don't know the amount of columns."